# Visual basic 2010 to open office base

Tags: vb.net, openoffice-base

How do i make the connection between visual basic and open office base, I can only find tutorials showing how to connecting to access.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link that may help:

[Working with Open Office in .NET](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2008/net-working-with-openoffice-3/)

Its a bit older, and somehow even older than that:

http://opendocument4all.com/content/view/68/47

and then the general information on the API

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/API_Intro